# Select one row with MAX(column) for known other several columns without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

My table contains votes of users for different items. It has the following fields:

```
id, user_id, item_id, vote, utc_time
```

I understand how to get the last vote of *#user#* for *#item#*, but it uses subquery:

```
    SELECT votes.*, items.name, items.price
        FROM votes JOIN items ON items.id = votes.item_id
        WHERE user_id = #user# AND item_id = #item#
            AND utc_time = (
                SELECT MAX(utc_time) FROM votes
                WHERE user_id = #user# AND item_id = #item#
            )
```

It works, but it looks quite stupid to me... There should be a more elegant way to get this one record. I tried the approach suggested here, but I cannot make it work yet, so I'll appreciate your help: [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql/2276247#2276247)

There is a second part to this question: [Count rows with DISTINCT(several columns) and MAX(another column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430426/count-rows-with-distinctseveral-columns-and-maxanother-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want just one row from the result, the one with `MAX(utc_time)`. In MySQL, there is a `LIMIT` clause you can apply with `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT votes.*, items.name, items.price
    FROM votes JOIN items ON items.id = votes.item_id
    WHERE user_id = #user# AND item_id = #item#
    ORDER BY votes.utc_time DESC
        LIMIT 1 ;
```

An index on either `(user_id, item_id, utc_time)` or `(item_id, user_id, utc_time)` will be good for efficiency.

Comment: That's smart... It's not that I want one row, there are simply cannot be more than one with such conditions in my table... Isn't it going to be potentially "slow"? Or when MySQL sees LIMIT 1 it will just fetch the maximum without ordering the whole table?

Comment: If it can use an index, it won't search (or order) the whole table (or the N rows that match the `WHERE` conditions). It will start from the (max) side of the index and fetch the first row only.

Comment: I see... Yes, I actually have an index there already. Thanks!

Comment: It works! Any idea what to do with this one (same table :): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430426/count-rows-with-distinctseveral-columns-and-maxanother-column/14430476#comment20089203_14430476

Answer (score 1):

Simple: if the date/time is the maximum date there will not exist a "higher" (more recent)  date/time (for the same {user,item} ).

```
SELECT vo.*
     , it.name, it.price
  FROM votes vo
  JOIN items it ON it.id = vo.item_id
 WHERE vo.user_id = #user# AND vo.item_id = #item#
   AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM votes nx
       WHERE nx.user_id = vo.user_id
       AND nx.item_id = vo.item_id
       AND nx.utc_time > vo.utc_time
       );
```

Comment: It still uses subquery... Isn't there a way to avoid it?

Comment: No,of course not. Even window functions and CTE's will invoke subqueries (in a different form) Window functions come closest, but mysql does not have them.

Comment: BTW: a sane plan generator would yield the same plan as for the LIMIT subquery (given appropiate indexes). Extremely sane generators would even recognise the MAX() to generate the same plan. BTW2: if there are two records with date=max(date), both will be found (since there is no order. The LIMIT (or rownumber OVER window) would avoid ties.